# How do I convert a list of lists into a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to convert a list of lists into a numpy matrix and then transpose it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `np.array`

```
x = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]

a = np.array(x)

a.transpose()

Out: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

a = [[0.2, 0.4],[0.4, 0.6],[0.4, 0.6],[0.20, 1.]]
pprint(a)

b = np.array(a)
b_t = b.T

pprint(b)
pprint(b_t)
```

The output is:

```
[[0.2, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6], [0.4, 0.6], [0.2, 1.0]]
array([[0.2, 0.4],
       [0.4, 0.6],
       [0.4, 0.6],
       [0.2, 1. ]])
array([[0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2],
       [0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 1. ]])
```